# Test whether virtual method has been overridden

Tags: c#, reflection

I know this is a bad idea, but I have a base class with *a lot* of virtual methods A(), B(), C() and a set of matching getters bool SupportsA(), bool supportsB(), ...

The idea is that implementers will only want to provide functionality for a small minority of virtual methods and I'd like to relieve them of the responsibility to also override the associated getter. Is there a way to tell from the base class whether *any* of the (potentially more than one) subclasses has overridden a specific method? Note these classes may be defined in different assemblies so I do not know the Type.

```
public class
{
  public bool SupportsA
  {
    get { return (A == overridden); }
  }
  public virtual void A()
  {
    // Null default implementation.
  }
}
```

There are some similar questions already, but they seem to assume that both the base type and the derived type are known at compile time.

Comment: Is there any reason for not using interfaces? Seems perfect for your requirements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class BaseClass
 {
    public bool SupportsA
    {
        get { return (this.GetType().GetMethod("A").DeclaringType == typeof(BaseClass)); }
    }
    public virtual void A()
    {
        // Null default implementation.
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, it even works within the base class constructor.